# Solve system of simultaneous equations in $3$ variables: $x+y+xy=19$, $y+z+yz=11$, $z+x+zx=14$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the following equation system:

$$x+y+xy=19$$
$$y+z+yz=11$$
$$z+x+zx=14$$

I've tried substituting, adding, subtracting, multiplying... Nothing works. Could anyone drop me a few hints without actually solving it? Thanks!

Comment: This is NOT, strictly speaking "linear algebra" because these equations are not linear.

Comment: Here is [a more recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3496931) about the same system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add $1$ to both sides of all the equations. To get
\begin{align*}
(x+1)(y+1) & = 20\\
(y+1)(z+1) & = 12\\
(z+1)(x+1) & = 15\\
\end{align*}
Now let $u=x+1,v=y+1,w=z+1$. And you have
\begin{align*}
uv&=20\\
vw&=12\\
wu&=15
\end{align*}
From this you can get
$$(uvw)=\pm 60.$$
Now use the above equations to compute $u=\pm 5$ and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Well, $x = (19-y)/(1+y),$ $y = (11-z)/(1+z),$ $z= (14-x)/(1+z).$ If you substitute for $z$ in the second equation, and then for $y$ in the first, you should get something of the form $x = (ax+b)/(cx+d),$ which is a quadratic equation...