# Solving the system $xy+x+y=-13$, $yz+y+z=-9$, $zx+z+x=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve for $x,\,y$ and $z$
> \begin{align*}
> xy + x + y &= -13\\
> yz + y + z &= -\phantom{1}9\\
> zx +z + x &= \phantom{-1}5
> \end{align*}

Obviously one way would be to substitute the value of $x$, $y$ and $z$ but that would get really ugly. Can anybody suggest a cleaner way to solve this equation?
I tried factoring, denoting the sum of the three variables as 's' and adding all the equations but couldn't make any progress

Comment: See also: [Solve system of simultaneous equations in $3$ variables: $x+y+xy=19$, $y+z+yz=11$, $z+x+zx=14$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1669228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$(x+1)(y+1)=-12,$$ $$(y+1)(z+1)=-8$$ and $$(z+1)(x+1)=6.$$

Thus, $(x+1)^2(y+1)^2(z+1)^2=576,$ which gives two cases:

1. $$(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)=24,$$ which gives
   $$x+1=-3,$$ $$y+1=4$$ and $$z+1=-2,$$ which gives
   $$(x,y,z)=(-4,3,-3).$$
2. $$(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)=-24,$$ which gives
   $$x+1=3,$$ $$y+1=-4$$ and $$z+1=2,$$ which gives
   $$(x,y,z)=(2,-5,1).$$

Comment: It's worth noting that (after adding 1 to the equations and factoring), one can solve for, e.g., $(x+1)^2 $ by multiplying two of the equations together and dividing by the third.  This allows one to determine everything (+1) up to a sign.  I mention this because it wasn't clear to me from the write up how we got the two solutions, and this is how I would have proceeded (noting that x+1 and z+1 have to have the same sign and y+1 the opposite sign).